# Asp contact page works locally but not on a server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp website and a contact form in asp that I found online. It runs perfectly on the local machine.

I added it to my server to test it live, and it didn't work. I got the display message to display the error, and it says this:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed. at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission
>   cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at
>   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Initialize() at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient..ctor(String host, Int32 port) at
>   contact.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   g:\pleskvhosts\myweburl\httpdocs\contact.aspx.cs:line 33 The action
>   that failed was: Demand The type of the first permission that failed
>   was: System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission The Zone of the assembly that
>   failed was: MyComputer

Does anyone know what this means?

My code for contact.aspx.cs is

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();

        mailMsg.From = new MailAddress(TheirEmail.Text);

        mailMsg.To.Add("myemailaddress@gmail.com");

        mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        mailMsg.Subject = "Contact Question!";

        mailMsg.Body = "Contact Details" + "<b>Name:</b>" + TheirName.Text + " <br/> <b>Email - address :</b>" + TheirEmail.Text + "<br/> <b>Comments :</b>" + Comments.Text;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

        mailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemailaddress@gmail.com", "mypassword");

        smtp.Timeout = 25000;

        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        smtp.Send(mailMsg);

        TheirEmail.Text = "";
        TheirName.Text = "";
        Comments.Text = "";


        DisplayMessage.Text = "Thank you. Your contact details and feed back has been submitted.";
        DisplayMessage.Visible = true;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DisplayMessage.Text = ex.ToString();
        DisplayMessage.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: Set  smtp.EnableSsl = false; Maybe your ISP does not support this? Also try Port 25

Comment: I googled my ISP and apparantly it does support SSL. I will change port to see if anything works

Comment: Well your ISP can support SSL but SSL is not FREE. That doesnt mean YOUR account has SSL. So please try smtp.EnableSsl = false;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your **`Web.Config`** file has the **`trust level`** set to **`full`**:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    .....
    <trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

For example, if you are using `GoDaddy`, you must set the following in **`System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`** variable (e.g. *smtp *):

```cs
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net", 25);
smtp.EnableSsl = false; // check if your ISP supports SSL
```

> You will also need to follow this page **[here](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5620/configuring-email-with-nopcommerce)** to properly configure Email on `GoDaddy`.

In some cases, if you cannot achieve `full trust`, having a lower security level will not allow you to specify an SMTP port. Your ISP specifies port **80**, but sometimes you can use the default which is **port 25** if 80 doesn't work.

Comment: my Web.Config file does not contain these words. This is all it contains pretty much <configuration>

    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>

Comment: Does the originUrl="" need to contain my website url, or does this remain blank?

Comment: Keep it blank, can you also answer my questions?

Comment: My ISP is Sky (im from the UK) and my port from my ip confirms im using port 80.

Comment: Is it still not wokring?

Comment: Can you post your send email method?

Comment: So, in contact.aspx.cs, where i have "SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)", should i change that to the GoDaddy info?
I am using GoDaddy for my site.

Comment: Sure, you can try that, I have updated my answer with a LINK to GoDaddy SMTP setup

Comment: I thought the smtp was there for the gmail server, which i thought was necessary for my gmail account. Is this not the case?

Comment: Did you try PORT 25 and setEnableSsl = False? I think you will need to use GoDaddy Email service since you are using their servers for hosting.

Comment: Oh wow, it worked! I changed the smtp from google to the godaddy info, and it worked! i disabled ssl for the time being but did not change port. and it worked! I will enable ssl to see if it still works. thank you for all your help. I would not have thought about that

Comment: Excellent, can you upvote and accept my answer if it has helped you

Comment: I will do that.
Enabling SSL did not work. Should I consider this as a security issue?

Comment: Well it could mean that your account doesnt support it. You may have to pay more money?

Comment: I'm having same mistake, but when I changed config file as you mentioned, it tarts throwing me an error in the ocnfig file. Could this issue be instead caused by other things like liberaries versions or something?

Answer (score -1):

Do this.....

```
mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = relay-hosting.secureserver.net;
smtp.EnableSsl = false;
```