# sending mail from my website in asp.net(C#)

Tags: asp.net

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.set_Port(Int32 value)
at feedbackcontrol.SendEmail(String toAddress, String subject, String body) in d:\inetpub\vhosts\platinumrealtee.com\httpdocs\feedbackcontrol.ascx.cs:line 38

The action that failed was: Demand The type of the first permission that failed was: System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission The Zone of the assembly that failed was: MyComputer
```

using this code in code behind file.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Label1.Text = SendEmail(txtTo.Text, txtsubject.Text, txtMsg.Text);
}

protected string SendEmail(string toAddress, string subject, string body)
    {
        string result = "Message Sent Successfully..!!";

        string senderID = "abc@gmail.com";// use sender’s email id here..
        const string senderPassword ="abcd"; // sender password here…

        try
        {
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com", // smtp server address here…
                Port = 590,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderID, senderPassword),
                Timeout = 30000,

            };

            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(senderID, toAddress, subject, body);

            smtp.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            result = ex.ToString();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: If your question is "What is going on", I'd say based on your description that you are getting an Exception!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  We require an actual question, rather than just giving an exception message without any explanation what-so-ever.  Please read the [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in the help

Comment: yes it exception but i am not able to send mail pls help me out

Comment: Error not well described, effortless on research part. nothing. Damn clueless. Only google can help you now

Comment: can you provide a simple code for the feedback form and when the user submit the form then information will come on the mentioned mail id

Comment: @SourabhSharma: you can get many related links if you try searching on net

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of what you want, have a look below

[Send Mail functionality in asp.net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-create-Contact-Us-Page-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Related mail code:-

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("sender@gmail.com", "receiver@gmail.com");
        mm.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        mm.Body = "Name: " + txtName.Text + "<br /><br />Email: " + txtEmail.Text + "<br />" + txtBody.Text;
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream, FileName));
        }
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
        NetworkCred.UserName = "sender@gmail.com";
        NetworkCred.Password = "xxxxx";
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);
        lblMessage.Text = "Email Sent SucessFully.";
    }
```

Also, you need to add `smtp port` and other related information properly to work as required

**UPDATE**

As it is not working on server, you need to add a setting in `web.config` file for it to work.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
       .....
    <trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You need to set `trust level set to full`

Reference taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433635/asp-contact-page-works-locally-but-not-on-a-server)

Comment: thanks for giving the answer bt it work only in local machine when i upload this code on the website then this exception will come

Comment: which exception, can you share the details ?

Comment: in my question exception is written?

Comment: Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using <location allowOverride="false"> from an inherited configuration file.

Line 24:     <customErrors mode="Off"/>
Line 25: <trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
Line 26:   </system.web>

Comment: I think u need to first learn basic asp.net. As u are not aware of what things are happening at your end and what u want to achive. Thanks.good luck Sourabh sharma

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example.  Remember it works better if smtp.port = 25;

```
  try 
  { 
           MailMessage msg = new MailMessage ();
           MailAddress fromAdd = new MailAddress("fromemail@email.com");
           msg.[To].Add("toemail@email.com");
           msg.Subject = "Choose Session Members";
           msg.From = fromAdd;
           msg .IsBodyHtml = true;
           msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
           msg .BodyEncoding = Encoding.Default;
           msg.Body = "<center><table><tr><td><h1>Your Message</h1><br/><br/></td></tr>";
           msg.Body = msg.Body + "</table></center>";
           SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient ("smtp.yourserver.com", "25");
           smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
           smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
           smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourname@yourserver.com", "password");
           smtpClient .DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
           smtpClient.Send(msg);
           smtpClient.Dispose();
        }
    catch (exception ex){
        Label1.Text  = ex.ToString();
    }
```