# Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission” in .NET when trying to use GoDaddy Hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I am created a web app in which I have given an option to send mail to the admin which looks like this

```
        var username = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
        var password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];

        MailMessage mails = new MailMessage();
        mails.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(username);
        SmtpClient smtps = new SmtpClient();
        smtps.Port = 587;   // [1] You can try with 465 also, I always used 587 and got success


        smtps.EnableSsl = true;
        smtps.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; // [2] Added this
        smtps.UseDefaultCredentials = false; // [3] Changed this
        smtps.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mails.From.ToString(), password);  // [4] Added this. Note, first parameter is NOT string.
        smtps.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

        //recipient address
        mails.Subject = subject;
        mails.To.Add(new MailAddress(username));
        mails.IsBodyHtml = true;
        string st = "Name: '"+UserName+"' <br/> Email: "+Email+"<br/>Phone Number: "+Contact+"<br/><p>"+message+"</p>";

        mails.Body = st;
        smtps.Send(mails);
```

this code is working fine in my local but,

> when I host this using Go Daddy

I am getting the following error

> ExceptionType : "System.Security.SecurityException"
>
> Message : "Request
>   for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed."

what should I need to do here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asp contact page works locally but not on a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433635/asp-contact-page-works-locally-but-not-on-a-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Web.Config file has the trust level set to full

```html
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    .....
    <trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

you must set the following in System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient variable (e.g. *smtp *):

```html
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net", 25);
smtp.EnableSsl = false; // check if your ISP supports SSL
```

You must go on this [link](https://it.godaddy.com/help/configurazione-email-con-nopcommerce-5620) to configure GoDaddy Email